# Plotting simple xyz 3d surface map in ArcMap GIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I'm a newbie in Arcmap and would like to map coordinates of X(Eastings) and Y(Northings) (eg, X=534911 Y=168822) against a Z-value (elevation).

I am trying to map a simple 3D surface to look at the location of the houses and understand the change in house price value (i.e. Z-value).

Example:[image: Example for Q]

I tried plotting this in Surface from Golden Software but I am unable to find out how to map it against a real time geographic map (e.g. Australia). Therefore I would like to ask if I can do something similar in ArcMap.

Comment: Not in ArcMap. You could investigate ArcScene.

Comment: You can display in arcmap, but it will be 2D - however, the z's can be represented as colors.  It is easy to import into arcmap.  Let me know if you want to know how to do it.  I haven't used ArcScene.

Comment: To compliment @PolyGeo you could also try the new ArcGIS Pro if that is available to you, but in both cases you'll need a 3D analyst extension  license.

Comment: It sounds like you have x and y coordinates representing the locations of house sales, and a z value representing the sale price, and you would like to create a 'price surface' for these data.  If so, use the Create TIN tool available in the 3-D Analyst tools.  Here is a link to more information.http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/create-tin.htm